# Parse Server Cloud Code error when sending push notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, parse-server, parse-cloud-code, back4app

Using Parse Cloud Code on back4app, I am trying to send a push notification after an object is saved:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('PFActivity', async () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.exists('deviceToken');
  await Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  data: { alert: 'notification' },
  useMasterKey: true
}).then(function() {
    // Push was successful
      console.log('Sent push.');
  }, function(error) {
      console.log('error push.');
      throw "Push Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
  });
});
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
> at ServerResponse.header (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
> at ServerResponse.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
> at ServerResponse.json (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
> at /usr/src/app/src/back/app.js:219:9
> at Layer.handle_error (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
> at trim_prefix (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
> at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
> at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

I would appreciate any suggestions for troubleshooting this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I had the formatting incorrect. This is working-

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('PFActivity', async () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.exists('deviceToken');
  await Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  data: { alert: 'notification' }
  },
      {useMasterKey: true}).then(function() {
    // Push was successful
      console.log('Sent push.');
  }, function(error) {
     // console.log('error push.');
      console.log("Push Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
      throw "Push Error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
  });
});
```